# Git: Interactively rebase a range of commits

Tags: git, rebase, git-interactive-rebase

I'm trying to `rebase -i` a few commits that occurred a while back in my history. Say I have a log like this:

```
* 5e32fb0 (HEAD -> master) Add latest feature
* 106c31a Add new feature
* 2bdac33 Add great feature
...100 other commits...
* 64bd9e7 Add test 3
* 3e1066e Add test 2
* 26c612d Add test 1
* 694bdda Initialize repo
```

and I want to squash the 3 test commits. In these circumstances, `git rebase -i HEAD~106` isn't very practical. What I'm looking for instead is something like `git rebase -i 64bd9e7:26c612d`.

Does git have this sort of behaviour, and if so, how can I use it?

I had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758128/how-to-git-rebase-i-for-a-range-of-commits), but it didn't answer my question.

Comment: It's rarely advisable to try to make a change that reaches that far back in history. Remember, anything you change in the past, also changes the present: every commit after the squashed ones is copied to a new, different commit, so as to provide this new history.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to squash those three commits, you'll need to re-write history for the *entire* repository. That is, all the commit hashes for commits after those test commits will be modified. The most straight-forward way to do it, in my opinion, is to:

1. Create a temporary branch and checkout pointing at `64bd9e7`.
2. Squash the three  commits together.
3. Checkout your main branch, and reset it to the commit immediately after `64bd9e7`.
4. Rebase it onto your temporary branch

Answer (score 23):

Just use `rebase -i` and squash only those commits.

```
git rebase -i <main_branch>
# Now just add `s` in front of all the commits you want to squash
```

If you have many commits, I'd suggest you to take a look at `rebase --onto` -

```
git rebase --onto <final_base_commit> <initial_base_commit> <head>

git rebase --onto 694bdda 64bd9e7 5e32fb0
```

Note: Rewriting history is an advanced operation, so tread with care.

[Git rebase tutorial](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

Answer (score 12):

You say "`git rebase -i HEAD~106` isn't very practical".

If you mean that the resultant script file is >100 lines long, it's not great, but it'll work.

If you mean that it's tedious to count back, to work out that you need the 106 commits - as sometimes happens to me, then there is a solution.

You need the hash of the *parent* of the earliest commit you want, then you can do:

```
git rebase -i <parent-hash> my-branch
```

Or you can do

```
git rebase -i <parent-hash> HEAD
```

which afterwards will leave you on a detached head that you can do what you want with.

So in your example, you could have done

```
git rebase -i 694bdda HEAD
```

(But I would still agree with the other comments, about whether you really want to be changing things that far back. I think it's a bit of a code smell, when I find myself doing it. It's unusual for me to have such a long branch without pushing/sharing it. I'd make a backup branch to test it on, too.)