# Apply range of commits from one branch to another

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-commit

I got 2 branches

```
a -- b -- c -- d -- e -- f -- g -- h     <-- master

a -- b -- c                              <-- Branch1
```

i need to apply the commits e, f and g onto Branch1

Tried with:

`git rebase --onto gSha1 eSha1 hSha1` after checkout on Branch1 and it didn't worked (as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45336654/12368797))

tried with `git cherry-pick eSha1^..gSha1` but it dont worked too (As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch))

Comment: Can you clarify real quick... your chart suggests that at some point Branch1 was merged into master. Is that the case? Or is it the case that your Branch1 is just behind master? Do `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` have identical commit hashes? In that case your chart should not show the merge line from `d` to `d`.

Comment: branch1 is just behind master.
They do have identical commit hashes.
They're not merged, i misunderstood the diagram

Comment: What does apply mean? What should happen to the original e f and g? What about h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want
 `a -- b -- c -- e -- f -- g`

From

```
                           E---F---G  master
                          /            
                         D
                        /
               A---B---C  Branch1
```

```
git rebase --onto branch1 dSha1 gSha1
```

will give you

```
                         E'--F'--G'  HEAD
                        /              
                       | D---E---F---G  master
                       |/
               A---B---C  Branch1
```

Next set Branch1 to HEAD:

```
git branch -f Branch1 HEAD
```

```
                         D---E---F---G  master
                        /
               A---B---C---E'--F'--G' Branch1
```

Alternative

Set Branch1 to master and rebase Branch1 on commit C without D:

```
git co Branch1
git reset --hard master
git rebase --onto cSha1 dSha1 Branch1
```

If you want
 `a -- b -- c -- d -- e -- f -- g`
(First question asked)

switch to Branch1

```
git checkout Branch1
```

then set Branch1 to g

```
git reset --hard gSha1
```

and here you are
you can push or continue

Comment: Does this apply the e, f and g commit from master branch to branch1?

Comment: Branch1 will be `a -- b -- c -- d -- e -- f -- g` there is story to apply commit, just set Branch1 to the commit g. You can see Branch1 as a pointer or a label on g

Comment: sorry, i changed my question

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `branch1` and then `git cherry-pick e f g`. Do not use a range; that squashes the commits into one.